# How to configure SQL Server access for guest OS?

Tags: sql-server, virtualization, virtualbox

What is the best way to configure a SQL Server on a host OS so that a guest OS can access it but it is not available outside the host OS?

I am using VirtualBox to host the guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

First, figure out how to set up a private network, possibly with NAT, between the host computer and the VirtualBox VMs. I've never used VirtualBox, so I can't guess as to the steps for doing this.

Once you've got a little private virtual LAN between the two, you can configure SQL Server to only listen on the IP address associated with that network. Run SQL Server Configuration Manager, go into the Network Configuration node, drill down to TCP/IP, and open the properties for it. On the IP Addresses tab you can configure which addresses SQL Server will accept connections on. You might want to also disable the Named Pipes protocol so that it doesn't inadvertently allow access to the outside network.

Answer (score 0):

Configure SQL Server to allow remote connections from your guest OS.  Here's a [tutorial with screenshots](http://support.webecs.com/KB/a375/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote.aspx).

Comment: Wouldn't the linked configuration expose the MS SQL Server to anyone outside the host OS?  I want to make sure only the host and any guest OS on the host can connect to the SQL server.